# UITableViewCell edit cell content on click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a question about `UITAbleViewCell`'s.

I have implemented `UITableViewDelegate` method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
}
```

After I click on desired cell, nothing happens...

Why it doesn't work as I expected? Also, what should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // config the selected cell
    ....
}
```

You should ask the `UITableView` for the cell directly rather than ask its delegate (`self` in your code). Cause its delegate may dequeue or create a fresh cell rather than giving you the cell seleceted.

Comment: @TomKortney Read my code carefully. I send a message to `tableView` directly rather than to `self`.

Comment: As far as I have seen, this answer is the clearest ant easiest one. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You have to create some base model for cell states e.g:

```
@property NSString *modelState = @"red"; // this is fast hint, but it can be a enum with states.
```

all cell will have one title after tap.

... other controller code...

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.restaurantTable  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell_ID"];
// cell customization method        
       [self customizeCell:cell accordingToStateStr:modelState];

        return cell;
    }
```

... other controller code...

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    // Set other state for cell
       self.modelState = @"red";

    [tableView reloadData];
    }

- (void)customizeCell:(UITableViewCell*)cell accordingToStateStr:(NSString *)str {
   if ([str isEqualToString:@"red"]) {
  cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Title";
   } else if(...) {
    //Other options..
   }
}
```

**[tableView reloadData];** - will trigger once again "cellForRow" method and your table will be redrawn according to new model.

You can use for cell states emuns instead NSString object (this is only scaffold for you).

Comment: You see, there is a problem, that I need to change not only a text. I need also to change a cell text label text color and cell background color...

Comment: @TomKortney For these type of things I would recommend using a model of some sort to hold the data for each cell. Then you could define the colors, text, etc, within the model. Another option would be to have another array of the same size holding a boolean value that tells you whether or not the cell is of the first style or second style. Then you would add an if statement to your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to set the style based on that boolean.

Comment: There is an option. But I would like to know why my way doesn't work? It seems to be good...